# SQL Server 2008 FullTextSearch Single Character in Name Missing from Results

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I have a full text indexed column in SQL Server 2008 which has the following rows:

> W Smithers, Wilda Smithers, W2 Smithers

When I run the following query I only get back Wilda Smithers and W2 Smithers.

```
SELECT  FT_TBL.full_name as results
FROM dbo.ft_table AS FT_TBL WITH (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE (ft_table , full_name, '("w*" AND "smither*")',12) AS KEY_TBL 
ON FT_TBL.ft_key_id = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
ORDER BY KEY_TBL.RANK desc
```

Any suggestions on how to tweak this so W Smithers is also in my result set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The W probably is a stop word. Try to remove it from the stoplist.

Check this link to see how it is done: [Configure and Manage Stopwords and Stoplists for Full-Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142551.aspx)

**EDIT**

Try to recreate the FT index, but this time do not specify any stop list at all.

[image]

Comment: I checked both "select * from sys.fulltext_stopwords" 
and "select * from sys.fulltext_stoplists" and no results were returned. I also checked "DB/Storage/Full Text Stoplists" in SQL Management Studio but that too was empty. Am I missing something?

Comment: When you created the ft index, did you specify what stop list you wanted to use?

Comment: Try to recreate the Ft index, but this time do not specify any stop list at all.

Comment: @RafaelColucci That's how mine was setup and it didn't work. I ended up having to manually specify an empty stop list.