# How to use contains with single character in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to use `contains` with single character in sql server.

In my Table Records are like

```
ID Data 
1  T 
2  T1
3  T2
```

When i use query like

```
Select * from table Where contains(Data,'"T*"')
```

my results look like

```
ID Data 
2  T1 
3  T2
```

I never got single character value like

```
ID Data 
1  T
```

for my requirement i don't want to use `like` or `charindex` statement. Please Help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008 FullTextSearch Single Character in Name Missing from Results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055425/sql-server-2008-fulltextsearch-single-character-in-name-missing-from-results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from sys.fulltext_stopwords
```

and

```
select * from sys.fulltext_stoplists
```

check it is returning anything

otherwise turn off the option stoplist to NULL in FULLTEXT INDEXING WIZARD