# Why isn't my single-character full text search working?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, sql-server-2014

Given this code, I'm getting back no results:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM MyTable WHERE CONTAINS(TextColumn, '"W"')
```

Things I've checked:

- Longer words return a result
- There are no stop LIST associated with this index
- There is definitely text such as "James W Brown" in the column
- The full text index is up to date.

EDIT: I was looking for a stop lists, not a stop word, associated with the index.

Comment: Are the quotes the problem?  (I've never used the contains function, I'd just use LIKE)

Comment: `CONTAINS` isn't for that kind of search, you can read about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx). Contains is for searching words or a prefix of a word and stuff like that

Comment: Quotes are required for searching for multiple words or ensuring that you don't mean a keyword such as "AND" or "NEAR".

Comment: And I'm searching for a  word that just happens to have one letter in it.

Comment: For that kind of search you'll have to use `LIKE` instead

Comment: This answer suggests that W may be a stop word (http://stackoverflow.com/a/13055506/1474939)

Comment: LIKE can't use indexes when looking for words in the middle of a string. Unless you are doing prefix searches or your table is tiny, LIKE is basically unusable.

Comment: I know that you won't be able to use an index, but a fulltext index isn't for searching letter, it's for searching prefixes or words

Comment: Again, I'm not looking for a letter. I'm looking for a word that is one letter long. There is a huge difference between the two.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055425/sql-server-2008-fulltextsearch-single-character-in-name-missing-from-results

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is to make sure you have an empty stop list associated with the index. It isn't enough to simply have no stop list, as it would just use the default stop list.

```
CREATE FULLTEXT STOPLIST [EmptyStopList] ;
GO
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON MyTable SET STOPLIST [EmptyStopList]
```

Answer (score 5):

`Full text Search` is a feature to do `Language Specific Search`.

The search may ignore the literal strings in the data and search for a specific word in a language , (Inflectional forms of a specific word, Synonymous  etc) which is specific to a language.

Here in your query you are looking for  the Letter "`W"` which isnt a word in english, its an alphabet but alone it doesn't mean anything. It is more like a pattren in a string for that purpose you should use `LIKE` key word along with wildcard `%` which will bring back the string value  `James W Brown`.

On the other hand if you a wanted to use FTS to find all the possible `James` in your database then FTS can be handy. By doing a THESAURUS search on James which will bring back Jim, Jimmy, Jimmie etc but then again you will have to edit the XML files under FDData for a specific language to make this happen.

Comment: looks like somebody is on a down vote binge, the answer posted by Jonathan has been downvoted too

Comment: There are some clowns unleashed dont worry about them. The little power they have in their lives , they tend to make the full use of it lollllllll

Comment: Full Text Search isn't limited to just words in a particular language. I can do `CONTAINS (StreetAddress, '"123"')` and get back "123 Main St.".

Comment: @JonathanAllen FTS for such search would be an overkill, `LIKE` should be used in your mentioned example.

Comment: @M.Ali Again, LIKE isn't the right answer. It does full table scans and doesn't understand the concept of whole words.

Comment: If you have an index on StreetAdress column,  `LIKE '123%'` will result in that index seek.

Comment: That was just a demonstration that FTS doesn't require a well known English word. Table scans come into play when not doing a prefix search.